# OpenGL ES 2 on Android: native window

Tags: c++, android, opengl-es2, mobile

According to OGLES specification, we have the following definition:

```
EGLSurface eglCreateWindowSurface(EGLDisplay display,
                                  EGLConfig config,
                                  NativeWindowType native_window,
                                  EGLint const * attrib_list)
```

More details, here: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/eglCreateWindowSurface.html

And also by definition:

```
int32_t ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(ANativeWindow* window, int32_t width, 
                                         int32_t height, int32_t format);
```

More details, here: http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api

I am running Android Native App on OGLES 2 and debugging it in a Samsung Nexus device. For setting up the 3D scene graph environment, the following variables are defined:

```
struct android_app {
    ...
    ANativeWindow* window;
};
android_app* mApplication;
...
mApplication=&pApplication;
```

And to initialize the App, we run the commands in the code:

```
ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(mApplication->window, 0, 0, lFormat);
mSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay, lConfig, 
                                  mApplication->window, NULL);
```

Funny to say is that, the command ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry behaves as expected and works fine according to its definition, accepting all the parameters sent to it. But the eglCreateWindowSurface does no accept the parameter mApplication->window, as it should accept according to its definition. Instead, it looks for the following input:

```
EGLNativeWindowType hWnd;
mSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay,lConfig,hWnd,NULL);
```

As an alternative, I considered to use instead:

```
NativeWindowType hWnd=android_createDisplaySurface();
```

But debugger says:

```
Function 'android_createDisplaySurface' could not be resolved
```

Is 'android_createDisplaySurface' compatible only for OGLES 1 and not for OGLES 2?

Can someone tell if there is a way to convert mApplication->window? In a way that the data from the android_app get accepted to the window surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using egl.h header from Android NDK?
In Android NDK EGLNativeWindowType is defined in eglplatform.h file (it is included from egl.h):

```
#elif defined(__ANDROID__) || defined(ANDROID)
#include <android/native_window.h>
...
typedef struct ANativeWindow*           EGLNativeWindowType;
```

As you can see EGLNativeWindowType has correct type - ANativeWindow*

Comment: If I use hWnd it does not complain, but the windowSurface does not work... I guess it expect to have the input instead from mApplication->window, which is initialized by android_app. But if I try to use mApplication->window as parameter for eglCreateWindowSurface, it complains that this parameter should be "unsigned long int". And this are my OGLES includes: <EGL/egl.h>
<GLES/gl.h>
<GLES/glext.h>
<GLES2/gl2.h>. Any thoughts?

Comment: Something is wrong with your headers or includes. Even the official NDK sample (native-activity) uses window member of android_app structure for eglCreateWindowSurface argument (linke 101 of main.c file). At it works fine there.

Comment: @Martins... do you mean that "eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay, lConfig, mApplication->window, NULL)" should work with on complaints about the paramenter "mApplication->window"?

Comment: Yes, it should work fine (compile without any warnings or errors), if you use egl.h header from NDK and mApplication->window has ANativeWindow* type coming from android/native_window.h file.